# Photo isn't sharp while uploading in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

Even after selecting the "High Resolution" image option in Facebook, the photo is losing its detail and clarity is very bad.

I tried exporting the image to PNG 24 using Photoshop for web usage. Still the image is not clear and the watermark text is too blurry.

This image is a JPG file from a Canon 6D.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook pretty aggressively compresses photos, even at supposedly high resolution. You can't really get an uncompressed photo on Facebook, even though some people [have complained for years](https://plus.google.com/+MikeElgan/posts/4XEma626LJp).

Comment: Very true, but in recent weeks I can see the images are compressed even more. Fonts goes blurry ! :(